can we change the native semantics of landmark elements or any element of html5 using aria
can we change the native semantics of landmark elements or any element of html5 using aria, is it semantically correct and conforming to do so ?
Suppose I want to use the  dialog element as a representation element, and want to know if we can change its role to either document or region to indicate that it doesn't serves as a usual dialog box.
I want to put the entire document structure inside the dialog element, making it the only direct child of the body element. I also want to use it as a container for other landmark areas of my document, like the heading, the nav, the header itself, the main element etc. all wrapped up inside their respective dialog elements too.
I am not well-versed in aria so i do not know how exactly to change the roles and other necessities to make the document semantically correct and conforming in a conformance checker.
I know that in html5 alone we can't do this in a valid way, I want to know if we can do this and still be semantically correct and conforming using ARIA ?

Why would you not have the  element contain a  element, like the example if your link? Why throw away the semantics of the  element if it's going to function as a dialog?

You can change the natural role of an element, but you are probably violating ARIA base principles.
Base principles of ARIA tell that you should first above all try to use the right element for the right thing, i.e. having the correct natural role without the need to override anything.
You should use ARIA only if you don't have any better solution. The rule is traditionally formulated as follows: use ARIA only if you have to.
In your case, it basically means that you should use <dialog> only for a dialog, just as you use <p> for a paragraph or <h1>-<h6> for headings and not something else.
Visual design isn't an excuse for choosing an unappropriate element, as you can always adapt your CSS.
Practically speaking, overriding the natural role of an element works most of the time, but by doing so, you are always taking the risk that changing that particular role from X into Y might not be supported with that particular assistive tool in that browser on that OS, due to various bugs and/or limitations at several layers (in fact there can be quite a lot of specialties, and they change constantly with updates).
The result is that the role stays X and if it wasn't what you meant, accessibility can be completely broken.
So it isn't recommended at all. You are much better and safer by using the right element for what it is originally meant to, and adapting your CSS.
